# Add animation one after another in div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to add a animation to a `div` one after the other when scrolled down to that point. I've three `<div>` in the same `row`.

The **HTML markup** is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="postCenter>Blah blah blah </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="postCenter>Blah blah blah </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="postCenter>Blah blah blah </div>
 </div>
```

I'm using the `viewportchecker` `jquery` plugin to trigger the event on scrolling.

The **jQuery** that I used is :

```
$('.postCenter').each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(1000*i);
        jQuery('.postCenter').addClass("hiddenClass").viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visibleClass animated bounce',
            offset: 200
        });
    });
```

Now the animation is happening all at the same time. The delay is not working I guess. How can I add the animation to the `<div>` one after the other?

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hs5nn412/

Comment: shouldn't that be `$(this).delay(1000*i).addClass("hiddenClass").viewportChecker({ ...`?

Comment: That's just a quick way of writing the statement. Didn't solve the problem. I tried that before.

Comment: The chaining is, yes, but you are also refetching all of the `.postCenter`  elements each time `.each` iterates.  In the above chain, it uses `$(this)`

Comment: I tried this. Its the same thing again :/

Comment: Could you set up a demo on http://jsfiddle.net or the like, linking the external library so we can test it easier?

Comment: Sure, hold on for some moments.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with it.  Is this the effect you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/d2e7os5c/ It seems like the kind of library that doesn't work well with delays.  If you still need delays, I suggest using the callback.

Comment: In the jsFiddle you provided, the div's are one after the other. But it should be on the same row. I think the trouble is here. and apprear it one after the other one

Comment: Nothing shows at all in the fiddle?

Comment: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/hs5nn412/2/

Comment: Aha! that makes so much sense now.  I should have seen that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what's going on now.  You want these three elements to fade in once scrolled to on the page, but you don't want them to fade in at the same time.  You want them to fade in sequentially with different delays.  I suggest a combination of `setTimeout` and the `callbackFunction` provided by the plugin.  The result is as follows:

```
$('.postCenter').each(function(i){
    $(this).addClass("hiddenClass").data('delay', i * 500);
}).viewportChecker({
    callbackFunction: function(elem, action){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(elem).addClass('visibleClass');
        }, $(elem).data('delay'));
    }
});
```

The concept is to index them, add the hidden class, and then use the callback function to add the classes after a setTimeout.

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uqc8d24s/ (note that I had to host the library myself.  I couldn't find a CDN for it and this demo may break in the future.  The fiddle OP provided keeps redirecting the hotlinked script to google).

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout()` should work.

```
$('.postCenter').each(function(i) {
    setTimeout( function(){
        $(this).addClass("hiddenClass").viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visibleClass animated bounce',
            offset: 200
        });
    }, 500*i ); 
});
```

Comment: Nope, same thing. Everything is appearing at the same time.

Comment: Updated. Should fix it, using `$(this).addClass()` @user1012181

Comment: It causes many errors and prevents the animations from happening

Comment: if the lack of `$(this)` is the issue, you should state that in your answer and not change the `.delay()` functionality.  Using `$(this)` may fix it, but the added `setTimeout` could be problematic.  Additionally, using `this` in a timeout function changes the context of `this` to be the `window` object.